# Does `SeedRandom` give the same set of random numbers across operating systems?

Tags: random

If I use

```
SeedRandom[12345]
RandomReal[{0,1},100]
```

I get the same random numbers on two versions of *Mathematica*:  10.4.1.0 on Windows 10 and 11.1.1.0 on Windows 7.

But does the same seed get the same set of random numbers on OS X and flavors of Linux?

Comment: Yes, the default algorithm is the same since some fairly old version. (A cellular automaton based one.) No, I don't have proof or a reference ready for you :(

Comment: As an example, `RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]` with `SeedRandom[12345]` gives `{0.121246, 0.329922, 0.782753}` on OS X, mathematica 11.0.0

Comment: Same on a Raspberry Pi too (which is 32-bit).

Comment: I believe it has been platform independent for many years now, possibly as far back as version 6 or so.

Comment: Thanks to all.  This is good to know.  I'll certainly start setting the random number seed in all of my future answers that involve random samples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turning Daniels comment into an answer:

> Random things with a fixed seed is platform-independent for many versions. The feature is implemented possibly since version 6.

I tested

```
SeedRandom[12345]
RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]
```

with version 11.2 on Linux and get the same output as provided by egwene sedai for OSX with version 11.0

```
{0.121246, 0.329922, 0.782753}
```

---

I've tested this also on version 2.2 on XP 32 bit (1993) and on 11.2 on windows 7 64 bit (2017). They also give same result. I do not have Mathematica version 1.0 to test this on.  Version 2.2 did not have `RandomReal` yet. So had to use loop to generate 3 numbers.

```
0.214347
0.539981
0.0875722
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But also noticed that `Random[Real, {0, 1}]` gives different random from `RandomReal[{0, 1}]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As an addendum: it is often a good idea to enclose any operations involving seeding in a `BlockRandom[]`, if you're concerned about interfering with the current random stream being used. As a typical example: suppose you are running a long Monte Carlo job, and in the middle of it, you need to generate a few random numbers unrelated to the Monte Carlo operation. You will then need to wrap that quick job in a `BlockRandom[]` so that the stream being used for the long job remains uninterrupted.

Comment: Older versions with `Random` will not be fully platform independent. `Random` may have become platform independent by version 5, I'm not sure. But that involved addressing some issues in 32 vs 64 bit platforms and also in endianness.

Comment: @Daniel, if memory serves, the current `Method -> "Legacy"` was the version 5 iteration, and versions before that didn't even have the cellular-automaton method, and just used plain "subtract-with-borrow".

Comment: @j.M. Not quite. A CA was used for some things, I think including machine reals. Somewhat different innards, it used rule 30 and I think the current one uses a different rule.

Comment: @J.M. Let me emend that. `Random` used (and probably still uses) rule 30 for machine integers (not reals) and bignum reals. SWB was used for big ints and machine reals. Go figure.

Comment: Yes, that got me confused a bit, @Daniel. I distinctly recall rule 30 not being mentioned in the implementation notes until version 5 (or maybe even 4.2 at the earliest).